# Error while trying to put files to hdfs : put: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PARSER

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, protobuf-java

When trying to put a local csv file to hdfs using :
hdfs dfs -put username.csv /data/
I getting the following error :

```
2022-02-13 01:25:58,989 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: DataStreamer Exception
java.io.IOException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PARSER
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufHelper.getRemoteException(ProtobufHelper.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:516)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.addBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1081)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1866)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1668)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:716)
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PARSER
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.getReturnMessage(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:306)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:278)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:123)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:514)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PARSER
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.HdfsProtos$LocatedBlockProto.<init>(HdfsProtos.java:18102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.HdfsProtos$LocatedBlockProto.<init>(HdfsProtos.java:18018)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.HdfsProtos$LocatedBlockProto$1.parsePartialFrom(HdfsProtos.java:18230)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.HdfsProtos$LocatedBlockProto$1.parsePartialFrom(HdfsProtos.java:18225)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:309)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$AddBlockResponseProto.<init>(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:17842)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$AddBlockResponseProto.<init>(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:17789)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$AddBlockResponseProto$1.parsePartialFrom(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:17880)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$AddBlockResponseProto$1.parsePartialFrom(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:17875)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:89)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:95)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcWritable$ProtobufWrapperLegacy.readFrom(RpcWritable.java:170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcWritable$Buffer.getValue(RpcWritable.java:232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.getReturnMessage(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:297)
        ... 18 more
put: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PARSER
```

Haddop Release :
Hadoop 3.3.1
Source code repository https://github.com/apache/hadoop.git -r a3b9c37a397ad4188041dd80621bdeefc46885f2
Compiled by ubuntu on 2021-06-15T05:13Z
Compiled with protoc 3.7.1
From source with checksum 88a4ddb2299aca054416d6b7f81ca55
This command was run using /opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.3.1.jar

Can someone help

Comment: Is the HDFS cluster you're trying to upload into also running 3.3.1?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes